# Aplicación web - Enviar email con el email del usuario

Tags: email

Estamos trabajando en un software de gestión donde queremos que el usuario pueda enviar emails a sus clientes desde la aplicación web con su email y que no sea con el nuestro propio de la aplicación. Resulta que para ello debemos tener el email y la contraseña del cliente pero dudamos en cuál es el mejor modo, si almacenar sus credenciales y encriptar y desencriptar la contraseña cada vez que envíe un email o si existe otro modo más seguro que éste ya que supone un agujero de seguridad.

Por otro lado, puede ser muy tedioso tener que estar instruyendo al usuario a configurar su proveedor de email (gmail, hotmail...) para que permita enviar estos emails desde nuestra aplicación.

¡Muy agradecidos por cualquier aportación!

Comment: Hola, ¿has pensado en usar Oauth2? Tal vez sea lo que necesitas. Claro, no todos los proveedores de correo ofrecen este protocolo, pero al menos las API Rest de gmail y outlook (hotmail) lo soportan.

Comment: gracias @MauricioContreras , creo que nos servirá!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con la libreria de PHPMailer y unos cuantos consejos de seguridad.

Puedes descargar el paquete de PHPMailer directamente aquí: https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/archive/master.zip

Una vez que hallamos descargado el paquete vamos descomprimir el contenido en un directorio llamado "PHPMailer" dentro de la raiz principal de nuestro sitio PHP y agregaremos mediante "includes" las librerías necesarias al principio de nuestra página PHP.

```
require_once('../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
include("../PHPMailer/class.smtp.php");
```

Ahora, crearemos un objeto y configuraremos algunos parámetros para enviar correo a través de nuestra cuente PHP:

```
$mail  = new PHPMailer();

//asigna a $body el contenido del correo electrónico
$body = "Contenido del cuerpo del correo"; 

// Indica que se usará SMTP para enviar el correo
$mail->IsSMTP(); 

$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     
// Activar los mensajes de depuración, 
// muy útil para saber el motivo si algo sale mal
// 1 = errores y mensajes
// 2 = solo mensajes entre el servidor u la clase PHPMailer

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
// Activar autenticación segura a traves de SMTP, necesario para gmail

$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
// Indica que la conexión segura se realizará mediante TLS

$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
// Asigna la dirección del servidor smtp de GMail

$mail->Port = 587;
// Asigna el puerto usado por GMail para conexion con su servidor SMTP

$mail->Username = "tucorreo@gmail.com";  
// Indica el usuario de gmail a traves del cual se enviará el correo

$mail->Password = "tu contraseña";
// GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last'); 
//Asignar la dirección de correo y el nombre del contacto que aparecerá cuando llegue el correo

$mail->Subject = "Probando enviar un correo con PHPMailer y GMail"; 
//Asignar el asunto del correo

//$mail->MsgHTML($body); 
//Si deseas enviar un correo con formato HTML debes descomentar la linea anterior

$mail->AddAddress("jonnathang@servidorcorreo.com", "Jonnathan Gutierrez"); 
//Indica aquí la dirección que recibirá el correo que será enviado

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Error enviando correo: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Correo enviado!!!";
}
```

Y de esta forma ya podrás probar el envío de correos desde PHP con tu cuenta de **GMail**. Si deseas probar enviar desde Hotmail/Outlook o Yahoo debes usar la siguiente combinación de servidores y puertos:

**Outlook/Hotmail**

```
$mail->Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = "tucorreo@outlook.com"; //o bien tucorreo@hotmail.com  
$mail->Password = "tu contraseña";
```

**Yahoo:**

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = "tucorreo@yahoo.com";
$mail->Password = "tu contraseña";
```

Con un poco de lógica, algunos if y buttons select's, puedes decirle al usuario que seleccione su servicio de correo e integras las API de las plataformas para el login o solicitas sus credenciales y las guardas encriptadas y que se transmitan por SSL.

**Algunos consejos finales:**

- En caso de querer enviar correo a través de gmail, hotmail, outlook o
  yahoo, asegúrate de usar en $mail->SetFrom(correo, nombrecontacto) el
  mismo correo que asignas a $mail->Username, si no lo haces tu
  servidor de correo o el servidor de correo del destinatario podrían
  marcar el correo como "SPAM" o un intento de suplantación de
  identidad y el correo nunca llegara a la bandeja de entrada del
  destinatario.
- Si deseas enviar publicidad mediante una página PHP te recomiendo
  respetar los limites de correos del sistema de correos que usaras.
  Por ejemplo GMail permite enviar solo 100 correos diarios. Tu cuenta
  de correo podría ser bloqueada por uno o varios días si superas esos
  límites.
- En caso de usar gmail, outlook, hotmail o yahoo, en $mail->Username
  debes usar el correo completo con dominio (tucorreo@hotmail.com,
  tucorreo@gmail.com...), no solamente el nombre de usuario.